# matplotlib detect object upon mouse event

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, mouseevent

Is there any way to detect the matplotlib object the mouse is focused on ?
this a piece of code that illustrates what i want

```
self.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.on_focus)

def on_focus(self, event):
    # get mouse position in figure
    figPos = (event.x,event.y)
    # get mouse position in axes if focusing on an axes
    axesPos = event.xdata, event.ydata
    # get axes instance if mouse is focusing on an axes
    axes = event.inaxes
    # get object (any matplotlib object, Text, Box, ...) mouse is focused on
    obj = event.??????
```

thanks

Comment: Do you want to know when the mouse _hover_ over an object or just when it clicks it?

Comment: basically when it hovers ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `Axes.hitlist`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10),range(10))

def on_focus(event):
    print ax.hitlist(event)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", on_focus)
plt.show()
```

But if you only want highlight you can use the built-in:

`fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event",fig.canvas.onHilite)`